# ComboBox with TextField

Tags: java, combobox, javafx-8, textfield

I would like to offer my user the choice between one of the predefined enums or an inputted int when using a ComboBox.

- I can't figure out why the text in the TextField keeps dissapearing.
- IndexOutBoundsException out of nowhere when using the ComboBox
- After selecting the TextField for the first time it dissapears in the ListView of the ComboBox but you can still select it.

Help appreciated

Runnable example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestComboBox extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ComboBox param2ComboBox = new ComboBox();
        TextField intTextField;
        intTextField = new TextField();
        intTextField.setEditable(true);
        intTextField.setDisable(true);
        param2ComboBox.getItems().addAll(Enums.Parameter.values());
        param2ComboBox.getItems().add(intTextField);
        param2ComboBox.setEditable(false);
        param2ComboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                if (newValue instanceof TextField) {
                    param2ComboBox.setEditable(true);
                } else {
                    param2ComboBox.setEditable(false);
                }
            }
        });
        param2ComboBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(param2ComboBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static class Enums {

        public enum Parameter {

            TW("TW"), TK("TK"), NJ("NJ"), TJ("TJ"), D("D"), NZ("NZ"), NW("NW");
            private String param;

            private Parameter(String p) {
                this.param = p;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried making my own CellFactory but I think it sucks :/

```
param2ComboBox.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Object>, ListCell<Object>>() {
    @Override
    public ListCell<Object> call(ListView<Object> p) {
        return new ListCell<Object>() {

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    if(item instanceof TextField){
                        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
                        setGraphic((Node)item);
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(null);
                        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
                        setText(item.toString());
                    }

                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ComboBox has a setCellFactory method that allows you to create your own custom ComboBox. Take a look at this example: 
[Custom Cell Factory](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/customcellfactory.htm).

Comment: Well I've used that one as example and the result is exactly the same with the CellFactory I wrote.